# JSON object update giving strange result

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am updating a json object which has internal array and each object of array has id element. Based on id element I update one of the element which matches the inout id, but it is modifying more than one object. My source code and console logs are given below which will help in understanding the issue.

### function

```
updateUserData(event,id){
    var elementName=event.target.name;
    console.log('id='+id+', element name='+elementName);
    var userData=this.state.user_data;
    console.log('User Data before change ='+JSON.stringify(userData));
    for(var i=0;i<userData.sports.length;i++){
       for(var j=0; j<userData.sports[i].ticket_detail.length;j++){
           if(userData.sports[i].ticket_detail[j].id==id){
               for(var k=0;k<userData.sports[i].ticket_detail[j].ticket.length;k++){
                   if(userData.sports[i].ticket_detail[j].ticket[k].paramname==event.target.name){
                       userData.sports[i].ticket_detail[j].ticket[k].value=event.target.value;
                      console.log('user data after change ='+JSON.stringify(userData));
                       this.setState({user_data:userData});
                       return;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
  }
```

### console logs

```
value=h

id=0, element name=name

User Data before change =
```

> {"total_tickets":3,"total_amount":2124,"htmlid_counter":3,"sports":[{"name":"Badminton","ticket_detail":[{"cat":"Men Singles","formid":102,"ticket":[{"label":"Name:","paramname":"name","type":"text","value":""},{"label":"Email:","paramname":"email","type":"text","value":""},{"label":"Phone:","paramname":"phone","type":"text","value":""}],"id":0},{"cat":"Men
>   Singles","formid":102,"ticket":[{"label":"Name:","paramname":"name","type":"text","value":""},{"label":"Email:","paramname":"email","type":"text","value":""},{"label":"Phone:","paramname":"phone","type":"text","value":""}],"id":1},{"cat":"Men
>   Singles","formid":102,"ticket":[{"label":"Name:","paramname":"name","type":"text","value":""},{"label":"Email:","paramname":"email","type":"text","value":""},{"label":"Phone:","paramname":"phone","type":"text","value":""}],"id":2}]},{"name":"Carrom","ticket_detail":[]}],"tournament_id":1}

```
user data after change =
```

> {"total_tickets":3,"total_amount":2124,"htmlid_counter":3,"sports":[{"name":"Badminton","ticket_detail":[{"cat":"Men Singles","formid":102,"ticket":[{"label":"Name:","paramname":"name","type":"text","value":"h"},{"label":"Email:","paramname":"email","type":"text","value":""},{"label":"Phone:","paramname":"phone","type":"text","value":""}],"id":0},{"cat":"Men
>   Singles","formid":102,"ticket":[{"label":"Name:","paramname":"name","type":"text","value":"h"},{"label":"Email:","paramname":"email","type":"text","value":""},{"label":"Phone:","paramname":"phone","type":"text","value":""}],"id":1},{"cat":"Men
>        Singles","formid":102,"ticket":[{"label":"Name:","paramname":"name","type":"text","value":"h"},{"label":"Email:","paramname":"email","type":"text","value":""},{"label":"Phone:","paramname":"phone","type":"text","value":""}],"id":2}]},{"name":"Carrom","ticket_detail":[]}],"tournament_id":1}

You can see from the abobe json , even though input id=0, but json object with id 0 , 1 and 2 are modified. Can someone help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. This issue was happening because each element of array was havinv reference to a common element. That was the reason when I was modifying any one of them, all were been modified.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a asynchronous setState at each iterations. that's probably why you are getting a weird result.

You have to build a new array, then, after your array is what you finally want in your state, you can do:

```
this.setState({ user_data: newArray })
```

Comment: That also I did but of no help

Comment: I found the issue. This issue was happening because each element of array was havinv reference to a common element. That was the reason when I was modifying any one of them, all were been modified.